# Can't figure out what is wrong with my merge sort code

Tags: java, sorting, merge

I went over it multiple times and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. 
he logic seems OK but it is printing out the first number only. I left out the main method:

```
public class MergeSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] bob = {4,7,99,8,12,6};

        Mergesort(bob);

        for(int i=0; i< bob.length; i++){
            System.out.print(bob[i]+",");
        }
    }

    public static int[] Mergesort(int[] bob){

        int length = bob.length;
        int mid = bob.length/2;
        if(length <= 1){
            return bob;
        }

        int[] left = new int[mid];
        int[] right = new int[length-left.length];

        for(int i=0; i< mid; i++){
            left[i]=bob[i];
        }
        for(int j=mid; j< length; j++){
            right[j-mid]=bob[j];
        }

        Mergesort(left);
        Mergesort(right);
        merge(left,right, bob);
        return bob;
    }

    //this is merge method
    public static int[] merge(int[] left, int[] right, int[] bob){
        int l= left.length;
        int r = right.length;

        int i=0, j=0,k=0;

        while(i<l && j<r){
            if(left[i]<=right[j]){
                bob[k] = left[i];
                i++; 

            }
            else
            {
                bob[k] = right[j];
                j++;

            }
            k++;
        }

        while(i<l){
            bob[k] = left[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        while(j<r){
            bob[k] = bob[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }

        return bob;

    }

}
```

Comment: second part of code

```public static int[] merge(int[] left, int[] right, int[] bob){
  int l= left.length;
  int r = right.length;
  int i=0, j=0,k=0;
  
  while(i<l && j<r){
   if(left[i]<=right[j]){
    bob[k] = left[i];
    i++; 
   }
   else
   {
    bob[k] = right[j];
    j++;
   }
   k++;
  }
  while(i<l){
   bob[k] = left[i];
   i++; k++;
  }
  while(j<r){
   bob[k] = bob[j];
   j++; k++;
  }
  return bob;
 }
}
```

Comment: Please include the `merge()` method _in_ your actual question.

Comment: @user4660931: You can use the "edit" link below your question to add that information.

Comment: When I try to add the merge method, stackoverflow is telling me my posts is mostly code so I can't post it..trying to fix it

Comment: @DavidWallace It does not.

Comment: Can you show exactly what it prints, please, and also what it prints if you comment out `Mergesort(bob);` in `main`?

Comment: @Ryan it prints out 4,4,4,4,4,4,. It prints out  4,7,99,8,12,6, if you comment out Mergesort(bob);

Comment: @DavidWallace still prints out 4,4,4,4,4,4,. I don't think printing the array is the problem. Somehow the first character in the array is replacing every other element.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your description of the problem.  I thought you were saying it just printed `4,` once.

Comment: It looks like Ole V.V. has identified the problem correctly, so I'm not going to try it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than just tell you the answer, I'm going to show you how to quickly figure it out via test/debug. You know, "teach a man to fish" and all that ([source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)).

So, let's **test** your `merge` method. I've modified the main method to only merge two sorted arrays `{1, 3, 5}` and `{2, 4, 6}`. We know that the output should be `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`.

At the same time, let's **debug** as well. The most primitive way to debug is known as "printf debugging," meaning we just put lots of logging statements in the code so that we can see what the internal state is at every step. I've added logging wherever your `merge` output array is modified. The goal is to observe the moment it is modified in an incorrect/unexpected way.

Here's the code with these two modifications:

```
public class MergeSort {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] left = {1, 3, 5};
    int[] right = {2, 4, 6};
    int[] merged = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    merge(left, right, merged);
  }

  public static int[] merge(int[] left, int[] right, int[] bob) {
    System.out.print("Before merge: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bob));
    int l = left.length;
    int r = right.length;

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    while (i < l && j < r) {
      if (left[i] <= right[j]) {
        bob[k] = left[i];
        System.out.print("Merge step 1: ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bob));
        i++;

      } else {
        bob[k] = right[j];
        System.out.print("Merge step 2: ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bob));
        j++;

      }
      k++;
    }

    while (i < l) {
      bob[k] = left[i];
      System.out.print("Merge step 3: ");
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bob));
      i++;
      k++;
    }
    while (j < r) {
      bob[k] = bob[j];
      System.out.print("Merge step 4: ");
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bob));
      j++;
      k++;
    }

    return bob;
  }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
Before merge: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Merge step 1: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Merge step 2: [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Merge step 1: [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
Merge step 2: [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0]
Merge step 1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0]
Merge step 4: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3]
```

So, where is the problem in your code? Clearly in "merge step 4," or the line `bob[k] = bob[j];`. How cool is that? With a few simple `print` calls, we've located the exact line of your bug!

Comment: I would NEVER do this!  All modern IDEs come with a debugger, which lets you look at all the values at each step, without adding stuff to your code.  People who get into the habit of adding `System.out.println` lines all over their code often FAIL to get into the habit of removing them once the problem has been found.  I've seen FAR TOO MANY of these ending up in production systems because a programmer was careless.  There is NO NEED for this.  Learn to use your debugger instead.

Comment: @DavidWallace I wouldn't do it either (in most cases). But it's better than doing nothing and expecting SO to find the answer for you. More to the point, I can't show you how to use a debugger in a text post, but I can show you how to printf debug. It's generally the first way that everybody learns to debug, and OP clearly needs to learn to debug.

Comment: @DavidWallace and these kinds of things *do* have a place in production systems. It's called logging. One purpose of logging is to aid in future debugging, and in some production systems, the only way to solve a new bug is to deploy a few new log lines. But that's a separate discussion. OP is clearly not writing production code. OP is failing to grasp the concept that it is possible to inspect the internal state of your code at runtime, and feeding OP an answer (rather than teaching them what they're missing) is equivalent to adding air to a leaky tire and thinking you helped the tire owner.

Comment: FWIW, to find the answer I posted, I first inserted a single `System.out.println();` statement in the program, when that wasn’t enough, fired up the debugger and began inspecting variables in each line of `merge()`. The production code at my work still contains a few `System.out.println` statements that people forgot to remove after them, and they are a bit of a nuissance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your bug is in this line in `merge()`:

```
        bob[k] = bob[j];
```

It should be

```
        bob[k] = right[j];
```

With this change I get this output:

```
4,6,7,8,12,99,
```